# Can I pour water out of a bottle?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, I have a "Bottled Water". I'm trying to get rid of the water so I have a plain bottle again.

Left clicking drinks the water. Right clicking drops the whole bottle, water and all.

How can I get my plain bottle back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to move fluids by hand, you need a [Bucket](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Buckets), rather than a bottle. Bottles are mostly for potion making.

In terms of converting the filled bottle back to an empty one -- you're out of luck. Your only option is to make a new one from sand.